# What to do if Google Search Console reports an error that the page should not be crawled at all?

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console has reported some errors that those pages should not be crawled recently. And it keeps going on.

The pages are never included in my `sitemap.xml`, nor I have put any link to those pages.

Is there any feature like "please remove/unindex the page"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Use this google webmaster tool to un-index the 
URL.https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Comment: wow, it seems still using the previous UI, not the latest console's. Is there a new version of this tool? Just wondering ...

Comment: Nothing I've found yet. Let me know if you find an upgrade.

Comment: Sure. New console has been live for years (not sure) but not too many upgrads ...

Answer (score 1):

Excluding a URL from the Sitemaps doesn't prevent it from being crawled or indexed. The only thing to make sure a URL is not being indexed is using [noindex](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en).

> Just make sure you are not blocking the access through robots.txt so searchers can find the noindex tag and prevent it from being indexed.

**Delete a URL using Google's tool**

The [Google URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal) is just temporary, so [it's not a permanent solution](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en).

> A successful request lasts only about 90 days. After that, your information can appear on Google search results

Comment: The page doesn’t exist at first place, how can I put the noindex attribute in it.

Comment: Use the X-Robots-Tag header (HTTP response header) with a value of either noindex or none. You can setup it through the web server.